# What actully happens in the background when a block is created?

Tags: nodeos, database

I want to know the whole background process of the block creation what is the actual implementation what happens?

Where it stores the data?
How it stores the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in BTC , 
block have hash of previous one,log of transactions (which is collection of actions),and a signature (who signed block)

Block have different hierarchy

```
Block
  Region
   Cycles (S)
    Shards (P)
     Transactions (S)
      Actions (S)
       Receiver and Notified Accounts (P)
   (s) - sequential , (p) parallel
```

Each EOS block is divided into cycles. Each cycle is divided into shards and each shard contains a list of transactions. Each transaction contains a set of Actions to be delivered. This structure can be visualized as a tree where alternating layers are processed sequentially and in parallel.

[image]

Above is a visualization of how a EOS block looks like. The Block contains two cycles, indicated by the black rectangular outline. These cycles are run sequentially, so the cycle on top will execute first before the cycle on the bottom.

Each cycle will contain many threads, as represented by the long, red rectangular outlines within the two cycles. These thread run in parallel, during each cycle.

[Referance from steemit post](https://steemit.com/eos/@bluabaleno/eos-whitepaper-walk-through-deterministic-parallel-execution-of-applications-structure-of-eos-blocks)